html and css to insert submenu dropdown items to the main menu
For my html navigation bar, I want to insert the submenus (namely, "one", "two" and "three") into the main menu, under the "Number" item and above "Data" item, when screen is small, which is similar to .
My html code snippet:
<section class="top-nav" style="padding: 5px;">
        <div style="font-family: Playfair Display, Georgia, Times New Roman, serif;">
          Menu
        </div>
        <input id="menu-toggle" type="checkbox" />
        <label class='menu-button-container' for="menu-toggle">
        <div class='menu-button'></div>
      </label>
        <ul class="menu">
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="index.html#dbs">Numbers</a>
              <ul class="submenu">
                  <li><a href="one.html">one</a></li>
                  <li><a href="two.html">two</a></li>
                  <li><a href="three.html">three</a></li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Data</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Knowledge</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </section>

and my css:
    /* Navigation styles */

    .top-nav {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-between;
      background: linear-gradient(to left, #008000, #932c24);
      color: #FFF;
      height: 40px;
      padding: 1em;
    }

    .menu {
      font-family: Playfair Display, Georgia, Times New Roman, "Liberation Serif", serif;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .menu > li {
      margin: 0 1rem;
      overflow: hidden;
      transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
      position: relative;
    }
    .menu > li:hover {
      background-color: #555;
      text-decoration: underline
    }

    .menu > li > a {
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    .menu-button-container {
      display: none;
      height: 100%;
      width: 30px;
      cursor: pointer;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

    #menu-toggle {
      display: none;
    }

    .menu-button,
    .menu-button::before,
    .menu-button::after {
      display: block;
      background-color: #fff;
      position: absolute;
      height: 4px;
      width: 30px;
      transition: transform 400ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
      border-radius: 2px;
    }

    .menu-button::before {
      content: '';
      margin-top: -8px;
    }

    .menu-button::after {
      content: '';
      margin-top: 8px;
    }

    #menu-toggle:checked + .menu-button-container .menu-button::before {
      margin-top: 0px;
      transform: rotate(405deg);
    }

    #menu-toggle:checked + .menu-button-container .menu-button {
      background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    }

    #menu-toggle:checked + .menu-button-container .menu-button::after {
      margin-top: 0px;
      transform: rotate(-405deg);
    }

   /* Main menu small screen*/
    @media (max-width: 767px) {
      .menu-button-container {
        display: flex;
      }
      .menu {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        margin-top: 50px;
        left: 0;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 100%;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
      }
      #menu-toggle ~ .menu li {
        height: 0;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        transition: height 400ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
      }
      #menu-toggle:checked ~ .menu li {
        border: 1px solid #333;
        height: 2.5em;
        padding: 0.5em;
        transition: height 400ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
      }
      .menu > li {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0.5em 0;
        width: 100%;
        color: white;
        background-color: #222;
      }
      .menu > li:not(:last-child) {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
      }
    }

    /* submenu styles */
    .submenu {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #008000;
      list-style-type: none;
      padding: 0.1em;
      margin: 0;
      border: 0.5px solid #ddd;
      top:50%
      left: 0;
      transition: opacity 0.2s ease, visibility 0.2s ease;
      line-height: 1.0;
    }

    .menu > li:hover .submenu {
      display: block;
      opacity: 1;
      visibility: visible;
    }

    .submenu > li {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 0.5em;
    }

    .submenu > li:hover {
      background-color: transparent;
    }
    .submenu > li > a:hover {
      text-decoration: underline;
    }

    .submenu > li > a {
      color: white;
      font-size: 14px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    /* submenu styles for small screens */
    @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
      .submenu{
        margin: 0;
      }

      .submenu > li > a{
        width: 100%;
        padding: 16px 70px 16px 18px;
        flex-direction: column;
        text-align: left;
        border-top: solid 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
        box-sizing:border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
      }
      .menu ul,
      .menu ul li ul{
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
        padding: 0 20px;
        position: static;
        box-sizing:border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
      }

    }
    .menu li:hover ul, .menu li:hover ul li ul {
      display:block;
      position: static;
    }


Meanwhile, I found the nav is big and covers my (× or hamburger symbol). How can I adjust it? I have tried for many runs but failed! Help Please.

It is happening because you have "position: static;" for the following class:
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
//...

 .menu ul,
  .menu ul li ul{
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0 20px;
    position: static;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  }

But you will have to come up with additional styles for when you have large screen, because if you comment it out, your code looks normal on small screens, but styling breaks on large screens.
